# Plot x,y,data in a heatmap with matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm having some trouble to plot data in a 2D heatmap using matplotlib.

The code is the following:

```
from ugtm import eGTM 
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


X_train = np.random.randn(100, 50)
X_test = np.random.randn(50, 50)

gtm = eGTM().fit(X_train)

responsibilities = gtm.optimizedModel.matR  

nodes_cumulated_responsibilities = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(np.sum(gtm.optimizedModel.matR,0).reshape(-1,1))

nodes_coordinates = gtm.optimizedModel.matX

transformed = eGTM().fit(X_train).transform(X_test)

Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(nodes_coordinates[:,0], nodes_coordinates[:,1],normed=True,
                                   bins=15,weights=nodes_cumulated_responsibilities[:,0])

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges,Z.T,cmap='bone_r')
plt.scatter(transformed[:,0],transformed[:,1],color='r')     
plt.title('np.hist2d')
```

I have the "nodes_coordinates" array shape(256,2) which represents the coordinates x,y of the nodes. Then i have "nodes_cumulated_responsibilities" array shape(256,1) representing the value of each node in the respective x,y coordinate. I also have a "transformed" array shape(50,2) representing 50 cells that "X_test" hitted in the heatmap by the eGTM.

Resuming, i would like to make a heatmap  using nodes_coordinates and nodes_cumulated_responsibilities as background, and then plot in this map a scatter plot of the "X_test" hitted nodes on the heatmap.

**But i want the scatter plot to be in the center of the node for any X_train or any X_test.**. This is whats i don't know how to do.

Some points for this code:

> The size of the map is 16x16 by default for any size of X_test, but it can be set to any integer, thus the map can be any nxn.

> The plt.pcolormesh needs the np.histogram2d to get a meshgrid with edges added to it. But i don't like to use np.histogram2d since i need to pass the 'bins' argument to adjust the heatmap correctly and i suspected it could lead me to some wrong maps or scatters.

> The np.meshgrid gives me a meshgrid for the heatmap but without the edges, so i cant use this with pcolormesh.

> The approach to use the plt.imshow to plot the heatmap using the np.meshgrid seems more trustable. But i don't know how to convert the 1D array "nodes_cumulated_responsibilities" to a 256x256 array.

A very similiar example of what i want to do is in: https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom/blob/master/examples/BasicUsage.ipynb

[Example of heatmap with scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLnkS.png)

Comment: I will use `plt.imshow`, and for last point you mentioned, use `reshape` can solve?

Comment: Also, pls use some toy data in your example code, which makes other easy to help u:)